# Issue with XML parsing in IBMi (XMLTABLE) xml

Tags: xml, db2, xmltable

I am trying to parse an XML with below structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<x12:ASC856_004010 xmlns:x12="http://abcd.com">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <CreationDateTime>2019-11-01T18:37:39.000Z</CreationDateTime>
        <DocType>TST</DocType>
    </ApplicationArea>
</x12:ASC856_004010>
```

I am not sure how to parse it when I have x12:ASC856 as the root node with name attached to it. I know that I can specify the namespaces with XMLTABLE to validate the XML with the XSD. To ease my parsing I changed the XML for time being to look like below

```
<LoadValues>
    <ApplicationArea>
        <CreationDateTime>2019-11-01T18:37:39.000Z</CreationDateTime>
        <DocType>TST</DocType>
    </ApplicationArea>
</LoadValues>
```

and it parses it happily with below query.

```
Select T1.* FROM Xmltable('$d/LoadValues' Passing Xmlparse(Document XML_Input) as "d" COLUMNS
DocType Varchar(10) Path '/ApplicationArea/DocType' ) as T1
```

Can some one help me to understand what this x12:ASC856 denotes?

When I parse the original XML I get the following error

> The XML parsing failed during SQL processing.  The byte offset into the XML value being processed after conversion to UTF-8 is 6.  The XML parser error description is: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Recovery  . . . :   Correct the XML value.  Try the request again.

Comment: x12 is a namespace

Comment: The error message seems to be complaining about the <?xml, not the root tag that follows it. Not sure whether that helps...

Answer (score 0):

This standalone example works on zOS 10:

```
Select T1.* FROM Xmltable(
XMLNAMESPACES('http://abcd.com' AS "x12"), 
'$d/x12:ASC856_004010' 
PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<x12:ASC856_004010 xmlns:x12="http://abcd.com">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-11-01T18:37:39.000Z</CreationDateTime>
    <DocType>TST</DocType>
  </ApplicationArea>
</x12:ASC856_004010>'
) as "d"
COLUMNS
   CreationDateTime TIMESTAMP Path 'ApplicationArea/CreationDateTime',
   DocType Varchar(10) Path 'ApplicationArea/DocType'
) as T1
```

- Added *XMLNAMESPACES* declaration
- Added the x12 namespace to the *row xquery expression*

Comment: Thank you stavr00 for your answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DB2 for IBM i (my 7.3 at least) doesn't accept XML prolog.
The following works as is, but not with the prolog uncommented.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM 
(
VALUES XMLPARSE
(
DOCUMENT 
'<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> -->
<x12:ASC856_004010 xmlns:x12="http://abcd.com">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-11-01T18:37:39.000Z</CreationDateTime>
    <DocType>TST</DocType>
  </ApplicationArea>
</x12:ASC856_004010>'
)
) V(X)
, XMLTABLE
(
  XMLNAMESPACES('http://abcd.com' AS "x12")
, '$d/x12:ASC856_004010' 
PASSING V.X as "d"
COLUMNS
   CreationDateTime TIMESTAMP   Path 'ApplicationArea/CreationDateTime',
   DocType          Varchar(10) Path 'ApplicationArea/DocType'
) as T1;
```